# Problems applying Math.round to a text field - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math

I’m trying to make a simple game that uses a basic equation:

‘linkCount’ / ‘clickCount’ * 100 to create a % success amount, ‘percentCount’

The text fields and the following as3 all live in a Movieclip on root level with instance name ‘counter_int’:

as3:

```
var clickCount:int = 1; //see below* for what controls this number
var linkCount:int = 1; //see below* for what controls this number
var percentCount:int = (100);

percentCount++;
percent_text.text = (int(linkCount) / int(clickCount) * 100 + "%").toString();
```

This works fine and displays a % amount in the correct field. However, my question is about truncating the % I get to remove anything after the decimal place. I’ve tried everything I can to get this to work but it’s not having it.

*

Now, here’s the tricky bit that i think is possibly causing my Math.round problem… I basically just don’t know where or how to apply the Math.round instruction?! I also suspect it might be a problem with using ‘int’ and have tried using ‘Number’ but it still displays decimal places.

I am using 2 buttons within 25 different movieclips…

Button locations:

all_int_circles_master.cone.FAILlinkbutton

all_int_circles_master.cone.linkbutton

all_int_circles_master.ctwo.FAILlinkbutton

all_int_circles_master.ctwo.linkbutton

etc … to ctwentyfive

The as3 on FAIL buttons:

```
FAILlinkbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick1);

function addClick1(event:MouseEvent):void

{
Object(root).counter_int.clickCount++;
Object(this.parent.parent).counter_int.clicked_total.text = Object(root).counter_int.clickCount.toString();
}
```

The as3 on successful link buttons:

```
linkbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickNextSlide2);

function onClickNextSlide2(event:MouseEvent):void

{
Object(root).counter_int.clickCount++;
Object(this.parent.parent).counter_int.clicked_total.text = Object(root).counter_int.clickCount.toString();
}
```

The % currently gets returned as e.g.:

74.334753434

but I need it to just be:

74

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can supply the .fla if necessary. This is kind of what I've been trying but no luck so far:

should the Math.round be applied at root level / globally somehow!?

should the Math.round be applied within the counter_int movieclip?

should the Math.round be applied within all of the all_int_circles_master.cone / two / three... movieclips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> percent_text.text = (int(linkCount) / int(clickCount) * 100 +
>   "%").toString();

I think you have your clickCount and linkCount backwards, swap those and round the results before adding the percent symbol:

```
percent_text.text = (Math.round((int(clickCount) / int(linkCount) * 100)).toString() + "%";
```

A pure AS3 example:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        var clickCount:int = 0;
        var linkCount:int = 30;
        var clicked_total:TextField;
        var button:CustomSimpleButton;

        public function Main() {
            button = new CustomSimpleButton();
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickNextSlide2);
            addChild(button);

            clicked_total = new TextField();
            clicked_total.text = "0%";
            clicked_total.x = 100;
            addChild(clicked_total);
        }

        function onClickNextSlide2(event:MouseEvent):void {
            clickCount++;
            if (clickCount < linkCount) {
                clicked_total.text = (Math.round((clickCount / linkCount) * 100)).toString() + "%";
            } else {
                clicked_total.text = "Done";
            }
        }
    }
}

import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

class CustomSimpleButton extends SimpleButton {
    private var upColor:uint   = 0xFFCC00;
    private var overColor:uint = 0xCCFF00;
    private var downColor:uint = 0x00CCFF;
    private var size:uint      = 80;

    public function CustomSimpleButton() {
        downState      = new ButtonDisplayState(downColor, size);
        overState      = new ButtonDisplayState(overColor, size);
        upState        = new ButtonDisplayState(upColor, size);
        hitTestState   = new ButtonDisplayState(upColor, size * 2);
        hitTestState.x = -(size / 4);
        hitTestState.y = hitTestState.x;
        useHandCursor  = true;
    }
}

class ButtonDisplayState extends Shape {
    private var bgColor:uint;
    private var size:uint;

    public function ButtonDisplayState(bgColor:uint, size:uint) {
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
        this.size    = size;
        draw();
    }

    private function draw():void {
        graphics.beginFill(bgColor);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks RobertN, the clicks in my case relate to ALL clicks, including links so the way I have it, links / clicks works ok and returns the correct % (the clickCount is always equal to or bigger than the linkCount value).
And, thanks for you solution too, to original question, both of them work a treat. I'll look into your class based solution too although I'm not really too confident!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
percent_text.text = (Math.round(int(linkCount) / int(clickCount) * 100) + "%").toString();
```

Comment: THANKS! I had tried similar* but this has FIXED IT :) I wish I'd asked 5 days ago.

*
    percent_text.text = Math.round (int(linkCount) / int(clickCount) * 100 + "%").toString();

^ but think I included the "%" inside the brackets.